# docker exec -it d16f0e1700ac /bash Error response from daemon: Container d16f0e1700a,,,,, is not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker

Hi Team I want start an exited container , for that i am giving below command.

docker exec -it d16f0e1700ac /bash

Then i am getting below error

Error response from daemon: Container d16f0e1700acf114f1ee36d2b58299e8de0595bc5a8ab6f69ca475f34cbfe939 is not running

Answer (score 0):

you have to **start** it, exec is only for running commands for already running containers, do

```
docker start d16f0e1700ac
```

Comment: still not working[root@ip-172-31-92-111 myapp]# docker start d16f0e1700ac
d16f0e1700ac
[root@ip-172-31-92-111 myapp]# docker exec -it d16f0e1700ac bash
Error response from daemon: Container d16f0e1700acf114f1ee36d2b58299e8de0595bc5a8ab6f69ca475f34cbfe939 is not running
[root@ip-172-31-92-111 myapp]#

Comment: what is output of `docker ps -a`

Comment: While giving docker ps -ad16f0e1700ac        biswa085/myapp3:1.0   "/bin/sh -c ['/usr/b…"   About an hour                                                                                         ago   Exited (127) 3 minutes ago

Comment: anyone plz assist here